# Resize button in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, button

Is there a way to resize a button in jQuery, I want the button to stretch across 70% of the page, but if I put `width="70%"` in the buttons tag, it still doesn't work, can someone please explain how to? Thanks :)
This doesn't work:

```
<a href="page.html" data-role="button" width="70%">Btn Name</a>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with CSS:

```
.big_button {
  display: block;
  width: 70%;
}
```

You should include the CSS class in your markup:

```
<a href="page.html" data-role="button" class="big_button">Btn Name</a>
```

Comment: Quick question how would I add jquery options like data-corners="false" in the css?

Comment: No that stays in the HTML - as a rule CSS is for style, HTML is for content

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="page.html" data-role="button" style="width:70%;display:block">Btn Name</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write the width in Stle tag and link it with your tags or buttons.